# Tabbing inside itemize (or itemize inside tabbing)

Tags: lists, itemize, tabbing

How can I combine the tabbing and itemize environments so that I'll have a list in which I can use tabstops?

```
- It would be nice             foo    bar
- If I could get this working  baz    quuz
```

I know I could just use an ordinary tabbing environment and fake the first "column" to always display a bullet point, but I'm sure there is a more standard solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about a table environment or `longtable` for breaking across pages.  Use the `listliketab` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\begin{document}

\storestyleof{itemize}
\begin{listliketab}
    \begin{tabular}{Llll}
        \textbullet &  It would be nice            & foo  &  bar   \\
        \textbullet &  If I could get this working & baz  &  quuz  \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}
\end{document}
```

It has the advantage that you can use `p` columns to wrap long lines, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I could make it work by "faking" a list environement using \textbullet. I was hoping to be able to use a itemize-like environment, but your solution is better than nothing, so thank you.

Comment: Follow-up question : how could one "fake" the numbers in the case of `enumerate` instead of `itemize`?

Answer (score 28):

You could employ the `tabto` package for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item It wouild be nice            \tabto{6cm} foo \tabto{7cm} bar
        \item If I could get this working  \tabto{6cm} baz \tabto{7cm} quuz 
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It's not entirely perfect though, as `tabto` does not always get the baseline right. In some occasions I had to use `\raisebox` or `\strut`s to fix this.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a (rather ugly) idea without using additional packages. Basically consists on making boxes of the desired size with `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \makebox[5cm][l]{It would be nice}             \makebox[2cm][l]{foo} bar
        \item \makebox[5cm][l]{If I could get this working}  \makebox[2cm][l]{baz} quuz
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```