# Skip to absolute position on line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning

Is there a way to skip to a fixed position on a line? (a specific tab position)

Example:

```
The quick \skiptoposition{1.5cm} brown \skiptoposition{2.5cm}fox
```

which would put "brown" 1.5cm and "fox" 2.5cm from left margin?

Comment: There is a `tabbing` environment, but I don't think that is what you need. This could be done using either `tikz` or the `zref` package by measuring the current position.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I have had great replies to my question!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The already mentioned `tabbing` package has the disadvantage that it cannot be used across paragraphs, for instance, in itemize environments, as asked in [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14038/tabbing-inside-itemize-or-itemize-inside-tabbing/14097#14097).

However, the `tabto` package provides exactly what you are looking for via the command `\tabto*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
  The quick \tabto{3.5cm}brown \tabto{5.5cm}fox
  \par
  \tabto{3.5cm}jumps too\tabto{5.5cm}far 
  \par\medskip 
  The quick \tabto*{1.5cm}brown \tabto*{3.5cm}fox
  \par
  \tabto{1.5cm}jumps too\tabto{3.5cm}far 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But that seems to result in a new line at each `tabto`?

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes, but only if the target distances are to small, that is, left from the current position in the current line (which was the case for the distances in the example of the OP). I have modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is almost perfect for my usage. I don't suppose there is any way of overriding the behavior of starting a new line if the tab is to the left of the current position. For my purposes I would like it to go to the defined tab position even if it caused text to overlap.

Comment: @Dan: Apparently this is possible by first doing a negative `\hskip` that is wide enough to then `\tabto` to the intended position. I have updated my solution accordingly (using a ridiculously large value for the negative `\hskip`).

Comment: @Dan: My [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)-solution allows for absolute spacing relative to text left margin within the given line. Or is that not what you're after?

Comment: You should add `\noindent` at the beginning of each `\par` so that things start from the left rather than indented.  This will also correspond to the other solutions for comparison purposes.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your \newcommand{\TABTO} does EXACTLY what I wanted, thank you very much. Amazed how helpful and knowledgeable everyone is here! Brilliant.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Using `\tabto*` instead of faking it is certainly more elegant! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Daniel Actually it was a suggested edit by an anonymous user that I improved before accepting, so the credit should go to that user for spotting this command.

Answer (score 12):

This is what `tabbing` is for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
  \hspace*{2cm}\=\hspace*{2cm}\=\kill
  The quick \> brown \>fox\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 'tabbing' environment works nicely but interferes with making boxes etc. Would like to do:
The \vskip0pt\vskip-(back to baseline)\hskip1.5cm brown fox

but do not know how to get the value to do the reverse skip back to the previous baseline. If I crunch a value in it works but I need it to work in all fonts/sizes etc.

Comment: This needs to be `\hspace*{1.5cm}\=\hspace*{1.0cm}\=\kill` to produce the correct output

Comment: @peter-grill: I increased the spacing to make the effect more visible.

Comment: Thanks Boris, the tabbing environment doesn't quite work for me in this scenario, but thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 11):

Less complicated than Werner's, but using more or less the same idea:

```
\noindent\makebox[2.5cm][l]{\makebox[1.5cm][l]{The quick}brown}fox
```

Just as an exercise, here is a different version implementing the idea of backspacing of Dan's comment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\startatpos}[2]{\hspace{#1}#2\hfill\cr\ignorespaces}
\NewEnviron{fixedpos}
   {\par\noindent\ooalign{\BODY\crcr}\ignorespacesafterend}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{1.5cm}{1pt}\par
\noindent\rule{2.5cm}{1pt}\par
\noindent\rule{3.5cm}{1pt}\par

\begin{fixedpos}
\startatpos{0cm}{The}
\startatpos{1.5cm}{quick}
\startatpos{2.5cm}{brown}
\startatpos{3.5cm}{fox}
\end{fixedpos}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there no way of ending a paragraph with a zero vertical advance (staying on the same baseline), then simply doing a \hskip to the desired horizontal position?
eg.
The \backskip\hskip1.5cm quick \backskip\hskip2.5cm brown \backskip\hskip3.5cm fox

I don't know how to do the \backskip (ie. go to beginning of line)

Comment: Thanks egreg. Great example for me to study further. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to use `\hspace{}` to control the skip.  The one complication is that you need to figure out how far you are to determine the second skip amount and that is where [the `calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) comes in.  Here is a macro version where you specify the positioning along with the text:

```
\AbsolutePosition[leading text]{position 1}{text 2}{position 2}{text 3}
```

For example:

```
\AbsolutePosition{1.5cm}{brown}{2.5cm}{fox}

\AbsolutePosition[The quick]{1.5cm}{brown}{2.5cm}{fox}
```

yields the first two lines between the guide rules.  The last two are to show that it works with font size changes as well (since you mentioned this in the comments):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\skipamount}
\newcommand*{\AbsolutePosition}[5][]{%
\noindent#1%                                 typeset first text
\setlength{\skipamount}{#2-\widthof{#1}}%    determine position of second text
\hspace{\skipamount}#3%                      skip to position of second text
\setlength{\skipamount}{#4-#2-\widthof{#3}}% determine position of third text
\hspace{\skipamount}#5%                      skip to position of third text
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{1.5cm}{1pt} 1.5cm\par
\AbsolutePosition{1.5cm}{brown}{2.5cm}{fox}\par
\AbsolutePosition[The quick]{1.5cm}{brown}{2.5cm}{fox}\par

\tiny
\AbsolutePosition{1.5cm}{brown}{2.5cm}{fox}\par
\AbsolutePosition[The quick]{1.5cm}{brown}{2.5cm}{fox}\par

\noindent\rule{2.5cm}{1pt} 2.5cm\par
\end{document}
```

---

Another method is to use a `tabular` environment. One complication in this case is the inter column spacing. To make this example easier to read I used `newcolumntype` from [the `array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array). First column is left empty to produce the spacing, and the second column is set to a width to get the next column in the correct spot.  The width of the last column is not that important (needs to be wide enough to accommodate the text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{@{}p{#1}@{}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{P{1.5cm}P{1.0cm}P{2.0cm}}
 &brown&fox
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

One advantage of this method is that position is absolute, so if the first word does not fit, the second word is still in the correct spot. Replace `brown` with `brownbrown` in the above example to see this effect.

Comment: 'tabbing' environment works nicely but interferes with making boxes etc. Would like to do:
The \vskip0pt\vskip-(back to baseline)\hskip1.5cm brown fox

but do not know how to get the value to do the reverse skip back to the previous baseline. If I crunch a value in it works but I need it to work in all fonts/sizes etc.

Comment: use `\widthof` to compute the size of the text and this will adjust for different fonts as I did above with `skipamount`.  If you want to align with something else (as opposed to absolute position), you could use `\phantom` but perhaps that is a separate question.

Comment: Updated `\AbsolutePosition` macro to accept an optional first parameter with the leading text that is to be displayed similar to the example that you gave.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your 'tabular' solution appears to work well for my needs, but requires further study for me to understand it (never seen the array package before). Your 'AbsolutePosition' command is great, and I can see all sorts of uses for that. Thanks very much for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about the elegance of this solution, but you could use an overlap via `\rlap{<stuff>}`, which sets its contents `<stuff>` in a zero-width box that is *left*-aligned - similar to `\makebox[0pt][l]{<stuff>}`, hence overlapping on the *right*. Horizontal alignment/spacing is provided by `\hspace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{1.5cm}{1pt}\hspace*{2cm}\verb!1.5cm! from left margin \par% Just for reference
\noindent\rule{2.5cm}{1pt}\hspace*{1cm}\verb!2.5cm! from left margin \par% Just for reference
\noindent\rlap{The quick}\rlap{\hspace*{1.5cm}brown}\hspace*{2.5cm}fox
\end{document}​
```

The horizontal rules above is just for reference to show the distance from the left margin as `1.5cm` and `2.5cm` respectively.

---

**Edit**: Here is an updated version that provides `\skiplmargin[<len>]{<stuff>}` which places `<stuff>` exactly `<len>` from the left margin. `<len>` is optional with a default of `0pt` which is flush with the left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref
\newcounter{posmarker}% Position marker counter
\newcommand{\skiplmargin}[2][0pt]{%
  \stepcounter{posmarker}% To avoid multiple references
  \zsavepos{currentloc\theposmarker}% Save current location
  \hskip\dimexpr-\zposx{currentloc\theposmarker}sp+\zposx{leftmargin}sp+#1\relax% Move left
  #2% Print argument
  \hskip\dimexpr\zposx{currentloc\theposmarker}sp-\zposx{leftmargin}sp-#1\relax% Move right
}
\AtBeginDocument{\zsavepos{leftmargin}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{1.5cm}{1pt} \hspace*{2.5cm}\verb!1.5cm! from left margin \par
\noindent\rule{2.5cm}{1pt} \hspace*{1.5cm}\verb!2.5cm! from left margin \par
\noindent The quick~\skiplmargin[1.5cm]{brown}~\skiplmargin[2.5cm]{fox}. \par
\noindent The quick brown fox.

\bigskip
\noindent\rule{3cm}{1pt} \hspace*{5cm}\verb!3cm! from left margin \par
\noindent\rule{7cm}{1pt} \hspace*{1cm}\verb!7cm! from left margin \par
\noindent The quick~\skiplmargin[3cm]{brown fox}~jumps~\skiplmargin[7cm]{over the lazy dog}. \par
\noindent The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

The main driver is [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module. A PDF position marker is placed at the start of `\skiplmargin` to memorize the location in the current line. Subsequently, a skip relative to the left margin is performed, `<stuff>` is typeset, and the skip is reversed. Space utilized by typesetting `<stuff>` is preserved, making it seem like the `<stuff>` was shifted out-of-place.

Caveat: You need to use ties `~` around `\skiplmargin` in order to preserve the spacing, which is otherwise lost due to the movement. Also, in `twoside` document mode with possibly different left and right margins, this approach may require some adjustment. This is due to the execution of `\zsavepos{leftmargin}` at the beginning of the document (`\AtBeginDocument`) in order to identify the left margin.

Comment: Is there no way of ending a paragraph with a zero vertical advance (staying on the same baseline), then simply doing a \hskip to the desired horizontal position?
eg.
The \backskip\hskip1.5cm quick \backskip\hskip2.5cm brown \backskip\hskip3.5cm fox

I don't know how to do the \backskip (ie. go to beginning of line)

Comment: It is possible to perform negative skips, but the way TeX constructs lines into paragraphs and paragraphs into pages make it hard to know "where you are exactly" on a line. I'll type up a solution that does this and report back.

Comment: @Dan: See my updated answer using the [`zref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref).

Comment: This is great Werner. The zref package is really interesting, and I can see lots of uses for it. I have had great replies to this question. Thanks so much for your help, and excellent example code.

Answer (score 6):

Short TeX solution (you need to pdfTeX rather than pdfLaTeX).

```
\newdimen\unit
\def\point(#1,#2)#3;{\rlap{\kern#1\unit
      \raise#2\unit\hbox{$
         \scriptstyle\bullet\;(#1,#2)$ #3 }}}


\hbox{\unit=10pt 
   \point(0,0) first;
   \point(8,0) second;
   \point(20,0) third test;
}
\bye
```

Don't know why Knuth calls such routines dirty though, in  Appendix D, of the TeX Book! You can add a fourth point  `\point(20,2) fourth test;` and see it can also tab vertically!

Comment: Maybe something like `\def\point(#1,#2)#3` would be clearer than using spaces to delimit the arguments. E.g., `\point(0,0){first}`

Comment: @TH You right, I edited the post.