# How to reproduce this thesis cover page in LaTeX?

Tags: thesis, covers

I am typing my thesis' cover page, our university has a typesetting requirement in this link

http://www.helsinki.fi/socialsciences/studying/current/thesis_cover.pdf

I need to reproduce this cover page in my LaTeX setting; could anyone teach me how to do this?

Comment: If my answer solved your question, you can accept it and we both get some karma.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `titlepage`environment. Assuming you're using a separate tex file for that, which you include using `\input{filename}`in your main file, your titlepage tex-file should look somewhat like this

```
\begin{titlepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %remove indent at new paragraph

\vspace*{5cm} %vertical space

\textbf{
    \huge{
        \textsc{
        The title of the series
        }
    }
}\\[25mm] %space after line

\textbf{
    \Large{
    Possible Subtitle   
    }
}

\vspace*{10cm} %vertical space

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{10cm} X}
&   Name \\
&   University \\
&   Faculty \\
&   Major \\
&   Date \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{titlepage}
```

This is a little sloppy. I didn't put in all the correct text from your example but I hope you get the idea of everything.

You will have to tweak the `\vspace*{distance}`a little and maybe also the `p{distance}`in the tabularx table. Regarding that, you will of course need

```
    \usepackage{tabularx}
```

in your preamble. There's other ways to align text (like the [tabto](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33487/skip-to-absolute-position-on-line) package), but I prefer tables.

Hope that helped; comment if you have questions.

Comment: There's also a great example here, on [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Custom_Title_Pages)

Comment: Why `\begin{table}`? It's not necessary.

Comment: True, in this case it's not. I'll remove it, for simplicity.

Comment: Just don't forget `\noindent`; but probably it's better to set `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` after `\begin{titlepage}` to have complete control over the various elements' position.

Comment: Good point! I got so used to having it in my preamble that I forgot to add it here. Will put it in now.