# Can the coding style of the algorithm environment be modified?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm using the packages

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

to produce a pseudocode of the following algorithm:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \centering
    \caption{Octree based search algorithm}
    \label{alg:octree-search}
    {\small
      \begin{algorithmic}
\Function{octree-search}{node=root, point, squaredDistance, nearestPoint=distant point}
  \For{octants of node}
    \State get subNode
    \State pointSphere = sphere around point using squaredDistance 
    \If{subNode has child nodes}
      \State subNodeBox = Axis Aligned Bound Box (subNode)
      \If{subNodeBox overlaps with pointSphere} 
        \State \Call{octree-search}{subNode, point, squaredDistance, nearestPoint}
      \EndIf
    \ElsIf{subNode is a leaf node}
      \State leafNodeBox = Axis Aligned Bounding Box (node)
      \If{leafNodeBox overlaps with pointSphere} 
        \State minimalPoint = distant point 
        \For{shape in node shapes}
          \State distanceToShape, shapePoint = \Call{signed distance}{shape, point}
          \If{$\|\text{distanceToShape}\| < \|\text{minimalDistance}\|$}
            \State minimalPoint = shapePoint 
          \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \State nearestPoint = minimalPoint \Comment return point of the recursive search 
      \EndIf 
    \EndIf
  \EndFor
\EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

And I'm using `\small` as the algorithm font size. Unfortunately, the page width causes problems and introduces line breaks like this:

[image]

As the whole point of the pseudocode (and clean code in general) is to use sensible names (for example squaredDistance in stead of sqD), I would like to re-format the output generated by the algpseudocode, for the function declaration so that it looks like this:

```
function OCTREE-SEARCH(
     node = root, 
     point, 
     squaredDistance,
     nearestPoint = distant point
)
```

without the ugly looking line break.

*Programming side-note*

I'm aware that the functions should ideally be monadic/diadic, but I'm interfacing my code with legacy code at this point and I cannot change the function signature. Reducing the argument number is therefore not an option.

**Edit**

Also, can the large horizontal space that comes before the `Comment` be somehow shortened?

Comment: Please edit your example code so that it becomes a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example shows how to add line breaks to the function definition.  This is done with a new pair of commands, `\FunctionTwo` and `\EndFunctionTwo`, analogous to `\Function` and `\EndFunction`, respectively. In this solution, each parameter must be preceded by a `\State` command which acts as a manual line break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{suffix}
\algblockdefx[funcDef]{funcStart}{funcEnd}[1]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}(}{)}
\algblockdefx[funcStarDef]{funcStarStart}{funcStarEnd}[1]{\textproc{#1}(}{)}
\algblockdefx[funcTwo]{funcTwoStart}{EndFunctionTwo}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}
\newcommand{\FunctionTwo}[2]{\funcStart{#1} #2 \funcEnd \funcTwoStart }
\newlength{\skipamount}
\newcommand{\CallTwo}[3][]{%
\setlength{\skipamount}{\widthof{#1\textproc{#2}(}}%
#1\textproc{#2}(#3)}
\newcommand{\StateTwo}{\State \hspace{\skipamount}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\CallTwo*[2]{\funcStarStart{#1} #2 \funcStarEnd }
\WithSuffix\newcommand\FunctionTwo*[2]{\State \CallTwo[\algorithmicfunction\ ]{#1}{#2} \funcTwoStart }
\WithSuffix\newcommand\EndFunctionTwo*{\EndFunctionTwo}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \centering
    \caption{Octree based search algorithm}
    \label{alg:octree-search}
    {\small
      \begin{algorithmic}
\FunctionTwo{octree-search}{\State node=root, \State point, \State squaredDistance, \State nearestPoint=distant point}
  \For{octants of node}
    \State get subNode
    \State pointSphere = sphere around point using squaredDistance 
    \If{subNode has child nodes}
      \State subNodeBox = Axis Aligned Bound Box (subNode)
      \If{subNodeBox overlaps with pointSphere} 
        \State \Call{octree-search}{subNode, point, squaredDistance, nearestPoint}
      \EndIf
    \ElsIf{subNode is a leaf node}
      \State leafNodeBox = Axis Aligned Bounding Box (node)
      \If{leafNodeBox overlaps with pointSphere} 
        \State minimalPoint = distant point 
        \For{shape in node shapes}
          \State distanceToShape, shapePoint = \Call{signed distance}{shape, point}
          \If{$\|\text{distanceToShape}\| < \|\text{minimalDistance}\|$}
            \State minimalPoint = shapePoint 
          \EndIf
        \EndFor
        \State nearestPoint = minimalPoint \Comment return point of the recursive search 
      \EndIf 
    \EndIf
  \EndFor
\EndFunctionTwo
      \end{algorithmic}
    }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \centering
    \caption{Alternative formatting}
    \label{alg:octree-search2}
    {\small
      \begin{algorithmic}
\FunctionTwo*{octree-search}{node=root, \StateTwo point, \StateTwo squaredDistance, \StateTwo nearestPoint=distant point}
\State \CallTwo{octree-search}{subNode, point, \StateTwo squaredDistance, nearestPoint}
\State \CallTwo{octree-search}{subNode, \StateTwo point, \StateTwo squaredDistance, \StateTwo nearestPoint}
\CallTwo*{octree-search}{\State subNode, \State point, \State squaredDistance, \State nearestPoint}
\EndFunctionTwo*
      \end{algorithmic}
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

With the line breaks added to the function definition, the whole algorithm looks like this:
[image: Output of example code, part 1]

The second picture shows alternative formatting choices for calls and function definitions. See the example code. Note that `\CallTwo` with `\StateTwo` cannot be nested in general. This is because only one variable, `\skipamount`, is used for the indentation level. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33493/23160) was a useful resource for me.
[image: Output of example code, part 2]

### Space before comment

The `\Comment` command seems to justify the comment text to the right. If there is a lot of space available and the comment text is short, this will leave a wide gap between the code line and the comment. One solution to reducing the gap is to pretend that the comment text requires more space than it actually does:

```
\State nearestPoint = minimalPoint \Comment \makebox[\width + 1cm][l]{return point of the recursive search}
```

This line would close the gap by one centimetre. Here one must experimentally find a suitable padding length. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30083/23160) by Werner is about length arithmetics with the `calc` package, as used in my example.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt' know that I have to explicitly klick on the bounty button. I did it just now. Thanks again for the nice answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I think the bounty would have gone to me even without an explicit click, as you had already marked my answer as accepted. http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/bounty