# Define a command to skip to an integer multiple of a length unit

Tags: macros, spacing, lengths

I wish to define such a command with which one can skip to a horizontal position that is an integer multiple of `1em`. For example, if one is at the position 1.2em from left, then with this command one should arrive at the position 2em from left.

I have some idea in mind using `\zsaveposx` of the `zref` package, but the code would be long and tricky. I also read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33487/skip-to-absolute-position-on-line), which mentioned the `tabto` package, which I think might be useful, but I don't know how much to tab to.

How could one define such a command?

Comment: using `\zsavepos` (or the underlying `\pdfsavepos` primitive) will always take at least two latex runs and be unstable if you have more than one of these in a paragraph, taking more runs to converge.  In almost all cases such an alignment is more naturally achieved  in tex using an `\halign` based alignment such as `tabular` or `tabbing`, what is the actual use case here?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using a typewriter font and am trying to make characters vertically aligned. Elements like math or non-monospaced character can disrupt this alignment and thus I want such a command to make the following characters aligned.

Comment: note that tex does a least cost line breaking calculation over an entire paragraph so adding a comma in the last line can affect the line breaking in the whole paragraph changing which is the "next" tab for any places in the para where you are using this command.

Comment: easier just to make sure every inline math expression is a multiple of your character width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How to "make every inline math expression is a multiple of character width"? I thought it was impossible as I was once told modifying math environment would be dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes use of the fact that lengths can be stored in `\newcount` registers as numbers (in sp units).  With this trick, I can divide two lengths using `\divide` and achieve truncation of the decimal portion.

The macro `\nexttab` tabs to the next increment of `\reflen`, here specified as 1em. In the MWE, I place an `X` at the next available tab location.  The rules underneath are there merely to confirm the authenticity of the tab.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newlength\reflen
\newcount\z
\newcount\refsp
\reflen=1em
\refsp=\reflen
\newcommand\nexttab{%
  \tabto*{0em}%
  \z=\TabPrevPos
  \divide\z by \refsp
  \tabto{\the\numexpr\z +1\relax\reflen}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is a test\nexttab X\\
This is a\nexttab X\\
This is\nexttab X\\
This\nexttab X

\noindent\smash{%
\rule{.02\reflen}{2ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{2ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{2ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{5ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{8ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{8ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{11ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `\reflen` is adjusted to 1.1em, the result is

[image]

Finally, we learn that a CM `m` is actually `0.84em` in width

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newlength\reflen
\newcount\z
\newcount\refsp
\reflen=.84em
\refsp=\reflen
\newcommand\nexttab{%
  \tabto*{0em}%
  \z=\TabPrevPos
  \divide\z by \refsp
  \tabto{\the\numexpr\z +1\relax\reflen}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is a test\nexttab mmmmm\\
This is a\nexttab mmmmm\\
This is\nexttab mmmmm\\
This\nexttab mmmmm

\noindent\smash{%
\rule{.02\reflen}{2ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{2ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{2ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{5ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{8ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{8ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{11ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{11ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
\rule{.02\reflen}{11ex}\rule{.98\reflen}{1pt}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the real use case is to ensure that inline math does not disturb the character alignment you can place it in a box that is a multiple of the character width, compare the first and second block here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\zz[1]{{\ttfamily\sbox0{$#1$}%
\sbox2{A}%
\makebox[\numexpr1+(\wd0/\wd2)\relax\wd2]{\usebox0}}}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\ttfamily


ABCDEF ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ZZ ABCDEF ONE WO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO Z $x^2+\alpha$ THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO Z THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN

\bigskip


ABCDEF ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ZZ ABCDEF ONE WO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO Z \zz{x^2+\alpha} THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO Z THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN
ABCDEF ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN

\end{document}
```