# Tabstop and line wrap inside itemize

Tags: lists, line-breaking, itemize, tabbing

What I am trying to achieve:

```
some list:
- some text
- Def.:  Some long text which should both automatically wrap to a new line
         and be tabbed as displayed here.
- some sublist
  * with the new counter
  * Def.:  same as above, but note that the counter matches the list level
```

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14039/17237) answer comes closest, but if used *inside* some other list, the counter (I mean the bullet point symbol) doesn't match, and the spacing before/after is larger. Also, I do not need the tabbing to work across multiple bullet points (as opposed to the original question), which might simplify things.

I hope my question is clear. Please let me know if not! It's not that I'm too lazy for a MWE, I just couldn't get anywhere close to what I want (other than a simple `itemize`). Thanks!

(Just to clarify: I do not want to specify any bullet point styles myself, it's just that they change with increasing list levels.)

Comment: How do you want to format long items that are not definitions?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I was planning on leaving them just as plain items in an `itemize` environment, i.e. with automatic line wrapping, some inline math, etc. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure you have specified all requirements, but here are three ways to tackle this.  The first is based on a `tabular` enviornment and will not allow new paragrahps in the indented text.  The second uses `minipage` and the indented text may now be broken into paragraphs.  The third is a suggestion of @egreg to use the enumitem package and a description list; this will break over pages, but does not generalise to further tabstops if you need them.

First the first two solutions:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\tabulardef}[3]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}lp{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1}@{}}
    #2&#3
  \end{tabular}}

\newlength{\standardparindent}
\setlength{\standardparindent}{\parindent}
\newenvironment{minipdef}[2]{\makebox[#1]{#2\ \hfill}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\standardparindent}\noindent\ignorespaces}%
{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Tabular example}

Some list:
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text which is long and wraps on to the next line as usual
  as this is demonstrating
\item \tabulardef{2cm}{Definition}{Some long text which should both
  automatically wrap to a new line and be tabbed as displayed here.}
\item Some sublist
  \begin{itemize}
  \item with the new counter and some text which is long and wraps on
    to the next line as usual as this is demonstrating
  \item \tabulardef{2cm}{Definition}{Some long text which should both
    automatically wrap to a new line and be tabbed as displayed here.}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Minipage example}

Some list:
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text which is long and wraps on to the next line as usual
  as this is demonstrating
\item \begin{minipdef}{2cm}{Definition}
    Some long text which should both automatically wrap to
    a new line and be tabbed as displayed here.

    This also contains new paragraphs with long text for demonstration
    purposes.
  \end{minipdef}
\item Some sublist
  \begin{itemize}
  \item with the new counter and some text which is long and wraps on
    to the next line as usual as this is demonstrating.
\item \begin{minipdef}{2cm}{Definition}
    Some long text which should both automatically wrap to
    a new line and be tabbed as displayed here.

    This also contains new paragraphs with long text for demonstration
    purposes.
  \end{minipdef}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

In the tabular case, there is a first column that is left aligned to contain the heading, and the subsequent text is in a `p` column.  Extra spacing before the first and after the last columns has been removed with `@{}` specifications.

The minipage case, sets the heading in a box first and then starts a minipage.  I have set things up so that subsequent paragraphs have the standard paragraph indent of the main text; without some indents it is hard to see where they begin.

Now the third solution with `enumitem`:

[image: Sample enumitem output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{deflist}{description}{2}
\setlist[deflist]{labelwidth=2cm,leftmargin=!,font=\normalfont}

\begin{document}
Some list:
\begin{itemize}
\item Some text which is long and wraps on to the next line as usual
  as this is demonstrating
\item
  \begin{deflist}
  \item[Definition]Some long text which should both automatically wrap
    to a new line and be tabbed as displayed here.
  \end{deflist}
\item Some sublist
  \begin{itemize}
  \item with the new counter and some text which is long and wraps on
    to the next line as usual as this is demonstrating
  \item
    \begin{deflist}
    \item[Definition]Some long text which should both automatically
      wrap to a new line and be tabbed as displayed here.

      This also contains new paragraphs with long text for
      demonstration purposes.
    \end{deflist}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using a nested list for the definition? With `enumitem` it should be simple.

Comment: @egreg Such a solution added, but it doesn't extend to multiple tabstops.  Image upload seems to be broken at the moment.  Will fix the image soon.

Comment: I don't understand what "multiple tab stops" should be. I'm afraid the OP is too much influenced by “other systems”. ;-)

Comment: Sorry for not having made my requirements sufficiently clear, and @egreg I didn't mean to ask for a "MS Word-like behaviour of TeX"... The third solution looks precisely like what I was looking for (no need for multiple tab stops), yet with simple code. Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Also I have to add that it's only through this solution that I just learned about the `description` environment... So thanks again!