# How to set tab in latex

Tags: enumerate, tabbing

I am trying to write something like that:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text
    <tab> text
    \item text
    <tab> text
    ...
\end{enumerate)
```

I found some solutions such as using     \ - or same things. But it's not work the same as tabbing. What should I write here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14038/24974

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please have a look on the link provided by `erik`

Comment: What does `<tab>` refer to in your question? Is it referencing the fact that you want `text` to be horizontally aligned?

Comment: @Werner yes, that what I mean

Comment: @Demyanov: This is the case by default if you leave a blank line between `text` and `<tab> text` (without the `<tab>`, of course). Alternatively, issuing a manual `\par` for `<tab>` also works.

Comment: @Werner Do you want to write an answer?